# VBA Match Function with Array

Tags: arrays, vba, match

when running below code I get "Object Required" error on the last line in the code. I cant really figure out why.

```
Dim FirstCurrentRange As Range
Dim FirstRowCounter As Long
Dim FirstArrayCounter As Variant
Dim FirstCurrentArray() As Variant

Dim ColumnCounter As Long
Dim ArrayCounter As Variant
Dim CurrentArray() As Variant
Dim SiteNameMatch As Long

Set FirstCurrentRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(InputSheet.Name).ListObjects("DataTable").Range
FirstArrayCounter = 0

For FirstRowCounter = 2 To FirstCurrentRange.Rows.Count
    FirstArrayCounter = FirstArrayCounter + 1
    ReDim Preserve FirstCurrentArray(1, FirstArrayCounter)
    FirstCurrentArray(1, FirstArrayCounter) = FirstCurrentRange(FirstRowCounter, 4).Value
Next FirstRowCounter

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DeleteMe.Name).Range("A1:A" & FirstArrayCounter).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(FirstCurrentArray)

ReDim Preserve CurrentArray(2, FirstArrayCounter)
ArrayCounter = 0

For ColumnCounter = LBound(FirstCurrentArray, 2) To UBound(FirstCurrentArray, 2)

SiteNameMatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(FirstCurrentArray(1, ColumnCounter).Value, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ContactListSheet.Name).ListObjects("ContactTable").ListColumns("Site").DataBodyRange, 0)
```

Comment: Add: Option Explicit, it will show you than (Inputsheet.Name, DeleteMe.Name & ContactListSheet.Name) need to be declared.

Comment: Option Explicit is already on. Not declaring the sheet names have not given me any issues earlier. I do something wrong with: FirstCurrentArray(1, ColumnCounter).Value

Answer (score 0):

why simple arrayCounters are variants instead longs?